# SQLAlchemy Sum after Group by Minute

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, aggregate

I am using SQLAlchemy and need to aggregate a PostgreSQL table `scores` such that every row contains the sum of all the `points` within a 1-minute period.

However, my attempt below leads to the error fails. How do we group by 1-minute periods?

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) function day(integer) does not exist
> LINE 2: FROM scores GROUP BY day(scores.timestamp), hour(scores.time...
> ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from db import postgres_session, postgres_engine

from models.Base import Base

class Score(Base):
    __tablename__ = "scores"

    timestamp = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    points = Column(Integer)


# Create table and add some rows
Base.metadata.create_all(postgres_engine)
# 6:45:xx AM GMT
postgres_session.add(Score(timestamp=1625985956, points=1))
postgres_session.add(Score(timestamp=1625985957, points=2))
postgres_session.add(Score(timestamp=1625985958, points=3))
postgres_session.add(Score(timestamp=1625985959, points=4))
# 6:46:xx AM GMT
postgres_session.add(Score(timestamp=1625985960, points=10))
postgres_session.add(Score(timestamp=1625985961, points=20))
postgres_session.add(Score(timestamp=1625985962, points=30))
# 7:02:xx AM GMT
postgres_session.add(Score(timestamp=1625986960, points=10))
postgres_session.add(Score(timestamp=1625986961, points=20))
postgres_session.add(Score(timestamp=1625986962, points=30))
postgres_session.commit()

agg = (
    postgres_session.query(func.max(Score.points).label('points'))
    .group_by(
        func.day(Score.timestamp),
        func.hour(Score.timestamp),
        func.minute(Score.timestamp),
    )
    .all()
)

for a in agg:
    print(a.timestamp, a.points)  # print out the minute timestamp and sum of points within that minute
```

---

**2nd Attempt:**

```
agg = (
    postgres_session.query(func.max(Score.points).label("points"))
    .group_by(
        func.floor(Score.timestamp / 60) * 60,
    )
    .all()
)
```

Error:

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/foo/test.py", line 43, in <module>
    a.timestamp, a.points
AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column 'timestamp'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The criteria used in a `GROUP BY` clause must be present in the `SELECT` clause, so you need to add them to your query.  And as the first error message states, there is no `date` function that matches your usage - you want to use `date_part` or `extract` ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)).

This query defines the group by columns in its `SELECT` clause and references the labels in the `GROUP BY`.

```py
agg = (
    postgres_session.query(
        func.date_part('day', func.to_timestamp(Score.timestamp)).label('day'),
        func.date_part('hour', func.to_timestamp(Score.timestamp)).label('hour'),
        func.date_part('minute', func.to_timestamp(Score.timestamp)).label('minute'),

        func.max(Score.points).label('points'))
    .group_by(
        'day', 'hour', 'minute'
    )
    .all()
)

for a in agg:
    print(a.day, a.hour, a.minute, a.points)
```

produces this output

```
11.0 6.0 45.0 4
11.0 7.0 2.0 30
11.0 6.0 46.0 30
```